# How to update nested array and objects in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update the state in react. However, still not clear how shall I do it. The nested structure is something like :

```
this.state ={
    permissionsObject:{
       fruitsGroup:[
         {
            index:0,
            taste:false,
            color:false,
         },
         {
            index:1,
            taste:false,
            color:false,
         },
       ],
       fruitsGroup:[
         {
            index:0,
            taste:false,
            color:false,
         },
         {
            index:1,
            taste:false,
            color:false,
         },
       ]
    }
}
```

Now, if I want to update the value of fruitsGroup -> taste based on the index value then how shall I proceed. I found there are various solutions exists for nested structure. However, none of them were answering my query or they are using react hooks while I'm not. Thanks well in advance.

Edit: The fruitGroup will have different name. So, how can I even locate it dynamically while setting the state.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";

export class App extends Component {
  state = {
    permissionsObject: {
      fruitsGroup: [
        {
          index: 0,
          taste: false,
          color: false,
        },
        {
          index: 1,
          taste: false,
          color: false,
        },
      ],
      groupName: [
        {
          index: 0,
          taste: false,
          color: false,
        },
        {
          index: 1,
          taste: false,
          color: false,
        },
      ],
    },
  };

  updateStateHandler = (idx) => {
    const updatedFruitsGroup = this.state.permissionsObject.fruitsGroup.map(
      (item) => (item.index === idx ? { ...item, taste: true } : item)
    );
    const newState = {
      permissionsObject: {
        ...this.state.permissionsObject,
        fruitsGroup: updatedFruitsGroup,
      },
    };
    this.setState(newState);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state)}
        <button onClick={() => this.updateStateHandler(0)}>
          Update index 0
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => this.updateStateHandler(1)}>
          Update index 1
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my query. However, I guess my query is not exactly answered if I filter according to index then where will I make the updations. What I mean to say is that suppose if I want to change the taste value to true whose index value is 1, then how am I supposed to do that ?

Comment: you can use `map` insted of `filter`,  I updated answer to use `map`

Comment: you can even pass second argument to handler with value you want to set either `true` or `false` , or any other

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Adding one more thing to my previous doubt if the fruitsGroups name will be dynamic then how can I locate it.

Comment: I tried the solution. However, it's not working.

Comment: it is working. You can pass `field`-`value` pair to update it